# Samsung 970 EVO is not recognized by BIOS

Tags: bios

I just bought a 970 Evo NVMe M.2 and installed on the M.2 slot of my laptop (Samsung NP500R5H), however it is not being recognized by the BIOS and it does't appear on the Windows Device Manager.

I have already tried to update my BIOS firmware, through the Samsung Update software, but it says that I am running the lates version (P08RDD), and I don't see any options to enable the M.2 slot.

Can you help me?

**EDIT**

I have added a picture of the slot that I am using in my motherboard.

[image]

Comment: Are you positive your laptop supports M.2 NVMe? M.2 SATA does exist and easily misidentified as M.2 NVMe.  Difficult to answer your question with the information you have provided.

Comment: I've uploaded a picture of my motherboard. I believe that this is a NVMe slot and not a SATA slot (if I am not mistaken, the SATA has a division to the left).

Answer (score 0):

There is almost no documentation for your model on the Samsung website,
so I had to resort to Crucial.

According to Crucial, for a similar model, the
[Samsung NP500P4C-S01US](https://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Samsung/np500p4c-s01us?searchTerm=NP500R5H&storeId=10151&catalogId=10151&langId=-1&pageSize=10&beginIndex=0&sType=SimpleSearch&searchFor=Keyword&resultCatEntryType=2&showResultsPage=true&searchSource=Q&pageView=),
only SATA 6.0GB/S is supported.

NVMe is rarely found on a laptop, and is more likely to be found on desktops.

I suggest replacing your SSD disk by one having the right interface.

Comment: Hum, I thought that my notebook had an NVMe slot (I've uploaded a picture). If it is there, shouldn't it work?

Comment: Hard to see from your photo, but it seems that the short stretch on the socket has 3 pins. You need 5 for “M key” and 6 for “B key". See [this article](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-know-if-my-laptop-has-an-M-2-SSD-socket).

Comment: @Felipe - If it’s SATA M.2 it absolutely will not work.  The fact it isn’t detected within the BIOS speaks volumes.

Comment: Well, I thought that since I do have a M slot, NVMe should work. This is very unfortunate since this piece of hardware was very expensive. I will try to search some more...